# Spring MVC and Tiles Definition Path

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, tiles, tiles-3

When i was going through tiles integration with spring, first i kept my tiles-definition in classpath to make the project more cleaner which resulted as the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [superlite] in context with path [/Superlite] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name 'home' in servlet with name 'superlite'] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'home' in servlet with name 'superlite'
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1190)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
```

servlet container was unable to see the tiles definition.
So, i migrated to commonly used directory structure: /WEB-INF/defs/tiles.xml.. which worked VERY WELL.
My curiosity is what happened so that servlet container wasn't able to see tiles definitions when i configure tiles-definition in classpath. Is there any solution for keeping tiles definition in classpath.

It would be much help if somebody could help me about this, so that i could sleep well at night.

Comment: What value did you use in the non-working solution, exactly?

Comment: I used `/WEB-INF/jsp/components/header.jspf` kind of values for defining web page templates.

Answer (score 0):

From what version of tiles did you upgrade from?

And what version of tiles did you upgrade to?

tiles resources, using spring-tiles integration from spring-3.2, are loaded through  ServletContextResourcePatternResolver.

see [SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext.java](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc-tiles3/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/tiles3/SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext.java)